# Xpages : Time Picker, Cannot type specific time (Domino 9 Server)

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, datetimepicker, timepicker

I need help regarding time picker in Domino 9.

I cannot type an specific time in the textfield. but when I try to put my application in domino 8.5, it works fine.

Time picker only allows time with every 15 mins. and I cannot modify it using the its textfield.
My output should be like this. (12:13 AM)

I there any solution regarding this issue?

regards,
Thanks!

Comment: Does this example `<xp:inputText
  id="inputText1"
  value="#{sessionScope.test}">
  <xp:this.converter>
   <xp:convertDateTime type="time"></xp:convertDateTime>
  </xp:this.converter>
  <xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
 </xp:inputText>` work for you? Just put it in a new XPage and test it.

Comment: Works fine with R9.0.1. Share your source, please.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]
I suggest you to check your version and install the FP2, since this FP corrects a bug related to the *default value of the pick date*. I'm sorry I can't test the Xpage now.

[original response]

In The standard client it works (I can edit the field), maybe should you install FP2 see http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd%5Cfixlist.nsf/WhatsNew/7ff6a78cb16153d085257d2b0062d7b8?OpenDocument. Which mentions:

> +HOKA8RZ5KL (LO67745) - Fixes issue in Xpages where the
>   correct date (or time) won't show on date time picker. This is a
>   regression in 8.5.3.

[image]

I tested with IBM Notes 9 
Social Edition

Release 9.0.1FP2 SHF202
Revision 20140804.1000-T00202SHF-FP2 (Release 9.0.1FP2 SHF202)

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is on the web, xpages and its about the time picker not the date.. any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @kennethJims he did it prior to you comment... see the title

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth I already modified it, any Ideas on how I can solve it? thanks